# Why use pandas.DataFrame.copy() for column extraction

Tags: python, pandas

I've recently seen this kind of code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/path/to/some/data.csv')
colX = data['colX'].copy()
data.drop(labels=['colX'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

I know that, to make an explicit copy of an object, I need `copy()`, but in this case, when extracting and subsequent deletion of a colum, is there a good reason to use `copy()`?

Comment: Well we don't know the intention here, the user may want a distinct copy of that column and then remove that column from the original df so they can freely operate just on that column without affecting the original df

Comment: But, how is the original dataframe being affected, if the column is removed from it anyway?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the user may want to separate that column from the main df, of course if the user just wanted to delete that column then taking a copy is pointless is pointless if their intention is to delete the column but for instance they didn't take a copy and instead took a reference then operations on that column may or may not affect the orig df if you didn't drop it. The main point here is that there is no context or indication of the user intent here

Comment: Ok, sorry if I was not clear on that. The intention IS extracting the column and immediately delete it. This is to separate the 'independent data' from the 'dependent' (or 'lables'). So thanks for pointing out that in this case the `copy()` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

@EdChum statet in the comments:

> the user may want to separate that column from the main df, of course if the user just wanted to delete that column then taking a copy is pointless if their intention is to delete the column but for instance they didn't take a copy and instead took a reference then operations on that column may or may not affect the orig df if you didn't drop it.